# Faster way to delete TB of data from GCP cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to delete 2TB of files from the GCP bucket.
I have read the GCP documentation for deletion and it says to use the gsutil -m rm command but when I am running it says 400+ hours estimate time.
Is there any faster way to do the deletion process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For buckets with a very large number of objects, one trick to deleting the contents is to use the Lifecycle Management feature. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle

Set a lifecycle rule that triggers when the object is 0 days old and an action of "Delete", and that should cause GCS to begin deleting your objects for you. Note that this may still take a while, as lifecycle rules can take up to 24 hours to go into effect, but that's still a lot better than a couple of weeks.

You can configure the lifecycle policy on a bucket from the console:

1. Head to https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser
2. Find the bucket you want to enable, and click None in the Lifecycle column.
3. Click Add rule.
4. Select the condition (object is 0 days old or )
5. Select an action (Delete the object)
6. Click continue.
7. Click save.

See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managing-lifecycles for more instructions.

N.B.: Lifecycle changes can take up to 24 hours to go into effect, so once all of your objects go away and you remove the lifecycle config setting, you should wait an additional 24 hours before putting any new files in the bucket, or else they might also get deleted.